# Trying to get vote total with get_vote.size and getting an undefined method for get_vote in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Pretty much what it says in my title. I'm using the Act As Votable gem and from my terminal the code is working with recording the vote and it's being stored in the Vote table. When I select the upvote button it gives me the error of undefined get_vote when trying to sum up the upvotes for a comment in a post.

I'm trying to set it up so that people can up upvote or a downvote a comment on a post.

**My routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
      member do
        put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
        put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
      end
  end
  root 'posts#index'
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
  acts_as_voter
end
```

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  acts_as_votable
end
```

**The View**

```
<div class="container">


<p>Title: <%= @post.title %></p></br>
<p>Category: <%= @post.category %></p></br>
<p>Body: <%= @post.body %></p></br>
<p>Date Created: <%= @post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></p></br>

<%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', @post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete #{@post.title}?"} %>

<% if user_signed_in?  %>
<%= render :partial => "comments/comment" %>
<% else %>
<%= "Please sign up or sign in to leave a comment." %>
<% end %>
</div>

<br />
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <% @post.comments.each do |f| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to like_post_path(@post), class: "like", method: :put do %>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
          <%= @post.get_upvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.text %></td>
        <td><%= f.try(:user).try(:username) %></td>
        <td><%= f.created_at %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  </div>

  <div>
    <%=  @comment.try(:user).try(:username) %>
  </div>
```

**My comments controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :upvote

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      redirect_to @post
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def downvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to @post
  end

private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:text, :user_id, :username)
  end

end
```

**Just in case these are my routes**

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#create
           post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
        new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
       edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
            post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
               like_post PUT    /posts/:id/like(.:format)                   comments#upvote
            dislike_post PUT    /posts/:id/dislike(.:format)                comments#downvote
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
                    root GET    /                                           posts#index
```

This is the error i'm getting

*NoMethodError at /posts/1
undefined method `get_upvotes' for #*

[Screenshot as well of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm6im.png)

Comment: Please include the _exact_ error message that you're receiving.

Comment: May I know version of acts_as_votable ?

Comment: I'm using this version gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.11.0'. I was working on this project and fell off of it for a few months because of work.

Comment: @grifftaur some of the error message is cut off. Please make sure the entire message is present.

Comment: You're only showing your model code for `Comment`, not `Post`, so can't say for sure – but most likely you don't have `acts_as_votable` declared in your `Post` model.

Comment: @jeffdill2 that was the problem. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have set up `Comment`  as `acts_as_votable` but you are calling `get_upvotes` on an instance of `Post`. Have you included `acts_as_votable` to `Post`?

(also, it seems like the error message you posted left some of the details off on what is receiving `get_upvotes`)

Comment: That is it! I had it in my comment model and not in my post model. Thanks for your help.